# Flying during the 9 days and watching movies

Tags: halacha, travel, nine-days, performance-entertainment

Is watching a (decent) movie during long international flight during the 9 days permitted?

In general since many types of pleasurable activities are limited during the 9 days I would think that movies fall under the not-permitted category, just like listening to music for pleasure. The only difference here is that here I am not so much seeking out a pleasurable activity as much as I am seeking distraction during a long and uncomfortable flight.

Comment: In general since many types of pleasurable activities are limited during the 9 days I would think that movies fall under the not-permitted category, just like listening to music for pleasure.  The only difference here is that here I am not so much seeking out a pleasurable activity as much as I am seeking distraction during a long and uncomfortable flight.  I am flying Sunday evening and would be grateful for some advice! (I do not want to ask LOR since I suspect the answer would be one should not watch movies 365 days a year!)

Comment: Questions asking for a practical ruling (_p'sak halacha_) are off-topic. For practical advice, [consult your rabbi](/q/9146). ([More information.](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734))

Comment: Also, in case this question *does* remain open to answers despite the fact that you indicated in a comment that you plan to rely on it for _p'sak_, can you [edit] to clarify why you think it will make a difference whether you're watching a decent movie (like _The Godfather_) or a poor movie (like _The Godfather Part III_)?

Comment: I didn't exactly mean that I would be relying upon someone's answer as a clear-cut psak.  Rather I'm looking for input that can help clarify the issue for me.  HueMan's answer is definitely that direction and I found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific issur to the act watching a movie in the nine days. However there is a concept of mimaatim bi'simcha, decreasing celebration. So we can imagine a range of more "celebratory" type movies, like comedies, to less celebratory,  like drama, to documentaries which aren't celebratory .

Assuming we are talking about non-assur content, it's  up to you to decide what you want to do and how much you want to be mimaet bi'simcha.

https://www.ou.org/holidays/the-three-weeks/laws_and_traditions_of_the_nine_days/ is a very good summation of these concepts.

Comment: Since few or none of us know who you are, we don't have any particular reason to take your word for what you say. So can you [edit] in sources for your claims?

Comment: https://www.ou.org/holidays/the-three-weeks/laws_and_traditions_of_the_nine_days/ is a very good summation of these concepts.

Comment: @HueMan, didn't mean it to be unwelcoming, sorry. I was just being (perhaps overly) explanatory about why sources are important.

Comment: @msh210 no problem